# password_hash not working on PHP 5.5.12

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.5.12 but i still get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `PASSWORD_DEFAULT()`

Why is this? Isn't `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` for PHP 5.5?

```
public function addUser($un, $pass)
{
        $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT());

        $sql = "insert into users (`username`, `password`) values ('$un', '$password')";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbh,$sql) or die(json_encode(array('error' => 0,'errorMsg' => "MySQL query failed.")));

        if(!$result) 
        {

        } 
        else 
        {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => 1,
                'errorMsg' => "Registered."
            ));
        }

}
```

Comment: Show the code you're having problems with.

Comment: PASSWORD_DEFAULT is a flag, not a function. `echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";` <-- right from the docs

Comment: please check http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is a **constant**, not a **function**.

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

In your code replace

```
$password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT());
```

with

```
$password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Got i missed that big time. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, feel free to upvote it and/or accept it!

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT());
```

to

```
$password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

it's a constant not a function

for more :- http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php